# Omit VHDs when exporting VM from Hyper-V

Tags: powershell, window, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have to export a VM from Hyper-V that has two VHDs attached to it, however I only want to include the VHD that has the operating system in the export. When I select export from Hyper-V manager, it seems to export either all or nothing. Is there any way for me to omit the second VHD? I will be incorporating this into a PowerShell script. We're running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do those other disks do? Is the exported VM going to work without them? Can you remove them from the VM prior to export?

Comment: The additional disk just stores backed up data. I should be able to remove them prior to export. Although I am not certain how to do this through a PowerShell script. I'll check through the documentation.